# Evaluation of $\int_{-v/2}^{v/2} \sqrt{1-\left(\frac{t}{7}-\frac{v}{14}\right)^2} \sqrt{1-\left(\frac{t}{7}+\frac{v}{14}\right)^2} dt$

Tags: calculus, integration, definite-integrals

I need to get the value of the following definite integral $v\in \mathbb R^+$

> $$\int_{-v/2}^{v/2} \sqrt{1-\left(\frac{t}{7}-\frac{v}{14}\right)^2} \sqrt{1-\left(\frac{t}{7}+\frac{v}{14}\right)^2} dt. $$

Comment: At first glance, this seems to lear to some very complex elliptic integrals.

Comment: If $v=2$, what happen?

Comment: I don't think that the value of $v$ is crucial as long as $0<v\leq 7$. It is very complex, for sure !

Comment: Is this homework ? If not, I think I could get a solution by tomorrow ... may be !

Comment: Of course, not.

Answer (score 4):

As I was suspecting, the antiderivative is just a nightmare; it includes a lot of elliptic integrals of different kinds.

Concerning the integral itself, I still had trouble for the general case. However, for specific values of $v$, I got some expressions which perfectly match the results of numerical integration.

Noting $$ I(v)=\int_{-v/2}^{v/2} \sqrt{1-\left(\frac{t}{7}-\frac{v}{14}\right)^2} \sqrt{1-\left(\frac{t}{7}+\frac{v}{14}\right)^2} dt$$ I obtained $$I(0)=0$$$$I(1)=\frac{4}{7 \sqrt{3}}-\frac{10}{7} F\left(\csc
   ^{-1}(13)|\frac{169}{225}\right)+\frac{985}{98} E\left(\csc
   ^{-1}(13)|\frac{169}{225}\right)$$ $$I(2)=\frac{2}{147} \left(21 \sqrt{5}-224 F\left(\csc ^{-1}(6)|\frac{9}{16}\right)+800
   E\left(\csc ^{-1}(6)|\frac{9}{16}\right)\right)$$ $$I(3)=\frac{2}{7} \left(\sqrt{10}-17 F\left(\sin
   ^{-1}\left(\frac{3}{11}\right)|\frac{121}{289}\right)\right)+\frac{3485}{294}
   E\left(\sin ^{-1}\left(\frac{3}{11}\right)|\frac{121}{289}\right)$$ $$I(4)=\frac{4}{147} \left(7 \left(\sqrt{33}-36 F\left(\sin
   ^{-1}\left(\frac{2}{5}\right)|\frac{25}{81}\right)\right)+477 E\left(\sin
   ^{-1}\left(\frac{2}{5}\right)|\frac{25}{81}\right)\right)$$ $$I(5)=\frac{1}{294} \left(140 \left(\sqrt{6}-19 F\left(\sin
   ^{-1}\left(\frac{5}{9}\right)|\frac{81}{361}\right)\right)+4199 E\left(\sin
   ^{-1}\left(\frac{5}{9}\right)|\frac{81}{361}\right)\right)$$ $$I(6)=\frac{2}{147} \left(21 \left(\sqrt{13}-40 F\left(\sin
   ^{-1}\left(\frac{3}{4}\right)|\frac{4}{25}\right)\right)+1160 E\left(\sin
   ^{-1}\left(\frac{3}{4}\right)|\frac{4}{25}\right)\right)$$ $$I(7)=\frac{7}{2} \left(5 E\left(\frac{1}{9}\right)-4 K\left(\frac{1}{9}\right)\right)$$

Outside the range $0 \leq v \leq 7$, the results are complex valued.

A quick and dirty least square fit, based on $71$ equally spaced values of $v$ between $0$ and $7$ shows that the result can be approximated as $$I(v)\approx 0.999563 v^{0.967758}-0.0011728 v^{3.93101}$$

**Added later**

Being frustrated of not getting the general solution of integral $I(v)$, I looked for more rigorous approximations. What I found is that the integrand can be very well represented by a $[4,2]$ Pade approximation $$\sqrt{1-\left(\frac{t}{7}-\frac{v}{14}\right)^2} \sqrt{1-\left(\frac{t}{7}+\frac{v}{14}\right)^2}=\frac{-\frac{4 t^4 \left(v^4+38416\right)}{49 \left(v^2-196\right)^3}+\frac{2 t^2
   \left(v^2+196\right)}{49 \left(v^2-196\right)}+\frac{1}{196}
   \left(196-v^2\right)}{1-\frac{4 t^2
   \left(v^2+196\right)}{\left(v^2-196\right)^2}}$$ anf then the integral is given by $$I(v)=-\frac{v \left(\sqrt{v^2+196} \left(v^4-294 v^2-19208\right) \left(v^4+784
   v^2-115248\right)-588 v \left(v^2-196\right)^3 \tanh ^{-1}\left(\frac{v
   \sqrt{v^2+196}}{v^2-196}\right)\right)}{294 \left(v^2-196\right)
   \left(v^2+196\right)^{5/2}}$$ which is a very good approximation.

Comment: I'm sorry, what is the definition of E, F, and K?

Comment: These are the elliptic integrals I was thinking about at first. $E(a,b)$ gives the elliptic integral of the second kind ; $F(a,b)$ gives the elliptic integral of the first kind; $K$ gives the complete elliptic integral of the first kind .

Comment: I greatly appreciate your description and answers. It would be very helpful to understand the problem.

Comment: You are very welcome !